# Docker port range binding using REST api

Tags: docker

I need to bind ports 1024 to 2048 to my host when running a container via **REST api**. I've tried using a similar syntax like in "docker run" but no luck:

```
    PortBindings: {
                    "1024-2048": [{ "HostPort": "1024-2048" }],   
                  }
```

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can't. You will need to list each port separately. However, given that it's done programmatically, this shouldn't be a problem. For reference, when do you create a docker container using the `docker` cli and you specify a range, e.g., `docker -p 1000-1010/tcp:1000-1010` and you then inspect the created container using `docker inspect`, you will see that in the shown details all ports in that range will be listed separately, too, e.g.:

```
            "PortBindings": {
                "1000/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "",
                        "HostPort": "1000"
                    }
                ],
                "1001/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "",
                        "HostPort": "1001"
                    }
                ],
                "1002/tcp": [
                 .....
```

Answer (score -2):

You are missing the protocol. From the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.24/#31-containers) for the Docker Engine API v1.24:

> PortBindings - A map of exposed container ports and the host port they
>   should map to. A JSON object in the form 
>   `{ <port>/<protocol>: [{ "HostPort": "<port>" }] }`
>
> Take note that port is specified as a string not an integer value.

So your request should have:

```
PortBindings: {
  "1024-2048/tcp": [{ "HostPort": "1024-2048" }],   
}
```

Comment: json: { message: 'invalid port specification: "1024-2048"' } } throws that error message